# How to send JSON response in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My JSON file(input.json) looks like below.

```
{"first_name":"Sabrina","last_name":"Mayert","email":"donny54@yahoo.com"}
{"first_name":"Taryn","last_name":"Dietrich","email":"donny54@yahoo.com"}
```

My Scala code looks like below. Here I am trying to return first_name and last_name based on email.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("RowCount").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val input = sqlContext.read.json("input.json")
val data = input
                .select("first_name", "last_name")
                .where("email=='donny54@yahoo.com'")
                .toJSON

data.write.json("input2")
sc.stop
complete(data.toString)
```

data.write.json("input2") creating file looks like below

```
{"value":"{\"first_name\":\"Sabrina\",\"last_name\":\"Mayert\"}"}
{"value":"{\"first_name\":\"Taryn\",\"last_name\":\"Dietrich\"}"}
```

complete(data.toString) returning response [value: string]

How can I get response array of JSON object.

```
[{"first_name":"Sabrina","last_name":"Mayer"},{"first_name":"Taryn","last_name":"Dietrich"}]
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting to json twice. Do not use the json conversion twice, and you should get your desired output:

```
  val data = input
            .select("first_name", "last_name")
            .where("email=='donny54@yahoo.com'")

  data.write.json("input2")
```

Output:

```
 {"first_name":"Sabrina","last_name":"Mayert"}
 {"first_name":"Taryn","last_name":"Dietrich"}
```

Does this solve your issue, or do you specifically need to convert it to an array?